# Oracle JDBC6 driver getConnection very slow

Tags: oracle, jdbc

I have a third party app which uses OpenJDK. It connects to an Oracle 12 Cluster, using OJDBC6.jar. All is well.

The Database folks have done an experimental upgrade to Oracle 19c. Since then, our app takes 3+ Seconds to get a connection using JDBC. (Used to take 50ms.)

I can't change the Open JDK that comes with the 3rd party app, so I am stuck with OJDBC6.jar. But I don't want to hold up the company move to Oracle 19C.

I have taken a tcpdump on the Linux box, and analysed it in WireShark. Nothing much jumps out. A TNS Connect Request, (Which happens twice, the server requests a resend), then some data flowing to the server, and some ACKs. All spanning over 3 seconds!

I can attach a screenshot of the capture if anyone wants it, but I'm a little nervous to do so, in case I accidentally show some confidential details.

Versions are:

```
O/S
Linux XXXXXX  3.10.0-1127.13.1.el7.x86_64 #1 SMP Fri Jun 12 14:34:17 EDT 2020 x86_64 x86_64 x86_64 GNU/Linux

openjdk version "1.8.0_202"
OpenJDK Runtime Environment (Zulu 8.36.0.1-CA-linux64) (build 1.8.0_202-b05)
OpenJDK 64-Bit Server VM (Zulu 8.36.0.1-CA-linux64) (build 25.202-b05, mixed mode)


java -jar OJDBC6.jar
Oracle 12.1.0.1.0 JDBC 4.0 compiled with JDK6 on Thu_Apr_04_15:06:58_PDT_2013
```

Does anyone have any ideas about how I might proceed further?

Update; I managed to get the product to use OJDB8.jar. Sadly, the issue persists.

Comment: Have you tried upgrading to a newer version of the JDBC driver? I'm not sure why using OpenJDK force you to stick on an older version for Java 6.

Comment: @MarkRotteveel Yep, I downloaded OJDBC8. If I run that (Java -jar OJDBC8.jar from within the app OpenJDK dir), I get a Java Version mismatch, so def not an option.

Comment: Based on [JDBC FAQ](https://www.oracle.com/database/technologies/faq-jdbc.html) for JDK8 and Oracle 19 you should use ojdbc8.jar. You do not *run* it, the driver is in the CLASSPATH.

Comment: You can "run" any OJDBC.jar file - it prints the versions of Oracle that it supports. But thanks for your help. I read the FAQs, I couldn't find clear answers on support for OpenJDK.

Comment: Edited question to show, clearly, the output of running the ojdbc6.jar, to determine suported versions.